# Table cell alignment

Tags: html, css

This little issue is starting to do my head in, I have read around a lot and have never had an issue with this in the past but I cannot seem to get the second div to appear on the right side of the table cell, any help would be appreciated.

My Markup is

```
<td>
    <div class="sort">
        <a href="#">ID</a>
        <span class="icon1"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="divider icon2"></div>
</td>
```

And my css is

```
thead .sort a {
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
}

thead .sort {
    float: left;
}  

thead .divider {
    float: right;
}
```

I am expecting this is something simple or something I am just overlooking.

Thanks,

Comment: Your CSS refers to `thead`, but there's no `thead` in your HTML. Is that a mistake when copying to here, or could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table .sort a {color: #f00; float: left;}
table .sort {float: left; border:1px solid #093;}  
table .divider {float: right; border:1px solid #00F;}
```

and

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="sort">
            <a href="#">ID</a>
            <span class="icon1"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="divider icon2">icon</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

works.

Note I just added a couple of borders to the CSS.

But then I just tried your code and that works here too.

Using `THEAD` or `TABLE` in the CSS seems to make no difference. Is it possible you have another style clashing with those used for the table?

Anyway, with the above CSS (referencing `table .SORT` instead of `THEAD .sort`), adding THEAD tags around a row in the HTML doesn't affect it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks David, that has helped, I have taken out all my CSS apart for the ones that could effect this and have found the problem, I was adding a bit of padding to the right side of the cell, this cell is so small the padding was pushing the icon up against the title. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cool, glad you found the prob, and happy to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

you are using `<thead>` in your `CSS` and yet in the `Html`, you are using `<td>`. Try use `<thead>` in your `Html`

Comment: I have thead, it goes <table><thead><tr><td> etc

Comment: I think your CSS then needs modifications, replace thead with div. Just thinking